# How can I compare 5 numerical arrays from the end to the start?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am making a discgolf scorecard and am stuck in the tee off order part.
I have 5 different arrays and I need to determine who will throw first on the next hole based on the previous scores on other holes. If people scored the same I need to check the score before that and so on. Lowest score throws first.

Example:

```
$player1score = array(3,3,3,3,4,3);
$player2score = array(3,3,3,3,3,4);
$player3score = array(3,3,3,3,2,3);
$player4score = array(3,3,3,3,3,3);
$player5score = array(3,3,3,2,2,3);
```

Each entry in the array represents the score on a previous hole.
If a player has the same score as someone else you look at the score before that to determine the order.

The output from the above needs to be something similar to:

- 1st: Player 5
- 2nd: Player 3
- 3rd: Player 4
- 4th: Player 1
- 5th: Player 2

**EDIT:**

As the starting position is the same as the numbering of the players the lowest numbered player should be listed first if they have the exact same score all the way. But the latest score in the array should be the first decider of position, not the entire sum of the array.

If the Arrays would be:

```
$player1score = array(3,3,3,3,4,3);
$player2score = array(3,3,3,3,3,2);
$player3score = array(3,3,3,3,2,3);
$player4score = array(3,3,3,3,3,3);
$player5score = array(3,3,3,2,2,3);
```

The output would be:

- 1st: Player 2
- 2nd: Player 5
- 3rd: Player 3
- 4th: Player 4
- 5th: Player 1

Comment: Do you have an example of some code you've tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I am afraid not, I have gotten stuck competely mostly due to the fact that the same value can be for multiple players and I then needs to go to the next set of numbers and compare.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: Seems like I have gotten 2 really interesting answers and I am truly grateful for the quick responses! I will have a look and test this in the application asap, i will ofcourse make sure to mark the answer that when I have verified it! Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcusHallbjörner Also FYI: You can take a little tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

First just put all player scores into one array `$players`. Then go through each player's score and use the key to determinate the weighting of each score and their position.

After this just sum all scores from each player together with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) combined with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) as callback.

Now you can sort your array ASC and keep the key to still remember which player has which position in the ranking, so for this use [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

At the end simply display the results.

```
<?php

    $player1score = array(3,3,3,3,4,3);
    $player2score = array(3,3,3,3,3,4);
    $player3score = array(3,3,3,3,2,3);
    $player4score = array(3,3,3,3,3,3);
    $player5score = array(3,3,3,2,2,3);

    $players = [
        $player1score,
        $player2score,
        $player3score,
        $player4score,
        $player5score,
    ];

    foreach($players as $outerKey => $player) {

        foreach($player as $key => $score)
            $players[$outerKey][$key] = ($key + 1) * $score;

    }

    $players = array_map("array_sum", $players);
    asort($players);

    $counter = 1;
    foreach($players as $key => $playerScore) {
        echo "$counter. player: " . ($key + 1) . "<br>";
        $counter++;
    }

?>
```

output:

```
1. player: 5
2. player: 3
3. player: 4
4. player: 1
5. player: 2
```

**EDIT:**

So I changed my code a bit and now it works as followed:

First of all I create a multidimensional array where I have the following data stored for each player:

- `scores` (each single score)
- `totalScore` (scores summed up with their weighting depending on their position)
- `position` (rank position)
- `player` (player number)

After declaring that array I loop through each player and calculate the total score (`totalScore`). Then I extract the `totalScore` column with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and sort it ASC with [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) to keep the player keys.

Now I can loop through the sorted array (`$totalScoresSorted`) and use the key to assign the correct position to each player in `$players`.

After that I can sort the entire `$players` array by `position` with [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to apply my own comparison function and keep the player keys.

At the end just simply display the data.

```
<?php

    $player1score = array(3,3,3,3,4,3);
    $player2score = array(3,3,3,3,3,4);
    $player3score = array(3,3,3,3,2,3);
    $player4score = array(3,3,3,3,3,3);
    $player5score = array(3,3,3,2,2,3);

    $players = [
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player1score),
            "totalScore" => 0,
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 1,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player2score),
            "totalScore" => 0,
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 2,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player3score),
            "totalScore" => 0,
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 3,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player4score),
            "totalScore" => 0,
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 4,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player5score),
            "totalScore" => 0,
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 5,
        ],
    ];


    foreach($players as $outerKey => $player) {

        foreach($player["scores"] as $key => $score)
            $players[$outerKey]["totalScore"] += ($key + 1) * $score;

    }

    $totalScoresSorted = array_column($players, "totalScore", NULL);
    asort($totalScoresSorted);
    $counter = 1;

    foreach($totalScoresSorted as $playerKey => $score)
        $players[$playerKey]["position"] = $counter++;


    uasort($players, function($a, $b){
        if($a["position"] == $b["position"])
            return $a["playerNumber"] > $b["playerNumber"] ? 1 : -1;
        return $a["position"] > $b["position"] ? 1 : -1;
    });


    foreach($players as $playerKey => $player)
        echo $player["position"] . ". position: " . $player["playerNumber"] . "<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
1. position: 5
2. position: 3
3. position: 4
4. position: 1
5. position: 2
```

**EDIT 2:**

As it turns out you want to sort your scores from the end to the start. So I changed the code again, but the array stays the same, expect that you don't need a total score anymore.

Now I simply compare the end values and if they aren't the same I already can return the one with the lower score.

If the are the same I go from the end to the start until the values are different. Then I check if both arrays are identical and if yes I choose the order by the player number. Else I again return the one with the lower score.

After sorting the array I only have to loop through the array again and set the position for each player.

```
<?php

    $player1score = array(3,3,3,3,4,3);
    $player2score = array(3,3,3,3,3,2);
    $player3score = array(3,3,3,3,2,3);
    $player4score = array(3,3,3,3,3,3);
    $player5score = array(3,3,3,2,2,3);

    $players = [
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player1score),
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 1,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player2score),
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 2,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player3score),
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 3,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player4score),
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 4,
        ],
        [
            "scores" => array_values($player5score),
            "position" => 0,
            "playerNumber" => 5,
        ],
    ];



    uasort($players, function($a, $b) {
        $scoresA = array_reverse($a["scores"]);
        $scoresB = array_reverse($b["scores"]);
        $i = 0;

        if($scoresA[$i] != $scoresB[$i])
            return $scoresA[$i] > $scoresB[$i] ? 1 : -1;

        while(isset($scoresA[$i], $scoresB[$i]) && $scoresA[$i] == $scoresB[$i])$i++;

        if(!isset($scoresA[$i]) || !isset($scoresB[$i]))
            return $a["playerNumber"] > $b["playerNumber"] ? 1 : -1;
        return $scoresA[$i] > $scoresB[$i] ? 1 : -1;
    });


    $counter = 1;
    foreach($players as $playerKey => $score)
        $players[$playerKey]["position"] = $counter++;


    foreach($players as $playerKey => $player)
        echo $player["position"] . ". position: " . $player["playerNumber"] . "<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
1. position: 2
2. position: 5
3. position: 3
4. position: 4
5. position: 1
```

Comment: Wow, never imagined so fast responses to this! I am amazed!
I will test this out as soon as I can later today!

Comment: Seems to mostly work great! I do however get odd results if one or 2 people have the same score. it seems to list it backwards, if player1 and player5 have the same score player 1 should be listed before player 5 as the initial start order is the same as the players numbers, Do I make sense?  Also if I just want each players starting position as an variable, so I have one variable for each players position or an array with integers as keys $playerposition[0] etc would that be possible?

Comment: @MarcusHallbjörner Yes that is correct that the order is reversed if 2 people have the same score. Now is the question if you want it in the correct order or, if 2 person can have the same place?

Comment: In the "right" order would be needed and they must have a unique position, as this is meant to guide the players to know who should throw first, they can't throw at the same time :D hehe Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcusHallbjörner updated my answer. So that if both players have the same score the player with the lower player number is first.

Comment: Again thanks for your work! I edited my question to give another example of the sorting needed. When  I ran your new code with the arrays above I got the output of Player 5 as the first player, however it would be player 2 that should go first as it is always the last value in the array that is deciding unless the value is the same for several players, then the second last value is checked and so on until a difference is found. Soz if I have explained this wrong, please let me know if any clarification is needed. Much Appreciated!

Comment: @MarcusHallbjörner If you look at your first example then player 3 should be 1st with your new edited sorting rule. So it was a bit unclear. But I updated my answer again (See: edit 2) and changed it so that it sorts the array as asked in your edited question.

Comment: You are a genious! That did it It works like a charm! So sorry for the confusions, I have learned alot today both from the code and the way of asking questions. Many Many thanks!!

Comment: @MarcusHallbjörner You're welcome. Enjoy your day :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after:

```
$scores = array(
    'Player 1' => array(3,3,3,3,4,3),
    'Player 2' => array(3,3,3,3,3,4),
    'Player 3 '=> array(3,3,3,3,2,3),
    'Player 4' => array(3,3,3,3,3,3),
    'Player 5' => array(3,3,3,2,2,3),
);

// should be set to total number of scores in each array
$total = 6;

$sorted_scores = array();

$i = $total;
while( $i > 0 )
{
    // decrement counter
    $i--;

    // get the current round's scores
    $this_scores = array();
    foreach( $scores as $player => $score_set )
    {
        $this_scores[$player] = $score_set[$i];
    }

    // clear duplicates
    $this_scores_values = array_count_values($this_scores);
    foreach( $this_scores as $player => $score )
    {
        if( $this_scores_values[$score] > 1 )
        {
            unset($this_scores[$player]);
        }
        else
        {
            // if this isn't a duplicate, remove from the main array so we don't re-use this player
            unset($scores[$player]);
        }
    }

    // sort remaining scores, low to high
    uasort($this_scores, function($a, $b)
    {
        if( $a < $b )
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return 1;
    });

    // add to sorted scores
    $sorted_scores = array_merge($this_scores, $sorted_scores);
}

print_r($sorted_scores);
```

The only thing this doesn't handle is the case where there are players with duplicate scores the whole way through. Perhaps extend it to include a check for anyone left in the scores array at the end and add them in whatever order to the sorted scores array.

Comment: Awesomely fast responses! I will have a look at this later today when I have the time to test it in my application and not just simulating the conditions. Big Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how to interpit the answer I get here. When i run the exact code I get it printed and the players are listed in the order in the array so far so good. But when i change any values in the arrays for example change Player1's last score from 3 to a 2 the order does not seem to change when running the code?

I won't need the score itself only the order they should start the next hole, if that is of any help. Thanks again!